# Matlab: Sort array by another vector taking ages

Tags: matlab

I have a vector `dG=rand(m,1);` and an array `lambda=rand(m,8);`

I sort `dG` in descending order and then sort lambda "row-wise" based on the newly sorted `dG`. The reason for this is that I want `5%` of the values from lambda based on the top `5%` of the newly sorted vector `dG`.

But when `m` is very large this process is very time-consuming. Is there a more efficient way?

For example:

```
m=1E10;

dG=rand(m,1); 
lambda=rand(m,8);

[~, Gsort]=sort(dG);
lambdaSorted=lambda(Gsort,:);
```

Comment: You do realize `rand(N)` creates an `N x N` matrix right? As a result, your `dG` matrix is `1E10 x 1E10`

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo. The question description is correct though.

Comment: And another thing: Posting pictures is never a good idea. You could have easily written that stuff on the picture as code. Like this I don't really get what's in your vectors. Something like `0-05` will most probably raise an error due to the leading zero. Why not just write `-5`? Or did you mean that a zero is supposed to be in the first, fifth and 25th element of the vector `dG`?

Comment: Ok, i understand, I'll take the picture away to avoid confusion.

Comment: 1e10 is a large amount of values to sort, it has to take some time. If precision is not an issue, casting `dG` to `single` will somewhat help. 1e10 double floats take 40GB memory, if that makes your system swap you are dead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`maxk`](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/maxk.html) instead of sort to extract top 5% of the values:

```
[~, Gsort] = maxk(dG, 0.05 * m);
lambdaSorted = lambda(Gsort, :);
```

If you have The Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox you can use [`prctile`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/prctile.html) to extract the `95nd` percentile of the elements. The option `'approximate'` doesn't use sorting to approximate the percentile and is good for large data.

```
p = prctile(dG, 95,'Method','approximate');
lambdaSorted = lambda(dG > p, :);
```

If you want to randomly permute an array you can use [`randperm`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html):

```
idx = randperm(m, 0.05 * m);
lambdaSorted = lambda(idx, :);
```

Comment: Thank you, I like this, but I'm using 2016a and it doesn't recognise maxk.

Comment: I've updated my answer suggesting two other methods.